# Vite + ViteSSG + Pinia load data before using useHead

Tags: vue.js, graphql, fetch-api

I'm trying to create a static site with Vite and ViteSSG and I want to set the pagetitle and the metadescription from my GraphQL data.

From what I've gathered, it's not possible to use Apollo and use await, so I've changed it to a fetch.

main.js:

```js
import App from './App.vue'
import { ViteSSG } from 'vite-ssg'
import { router } from './router.js'
import { provideApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/core'

const cache = new InMemoryCache()

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  uri: 'https://localhost:44351/graphql/'
})

provideApolloClient(apolloClient)

import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import { usePagesStore } from './stores/pages'

export const createApp = ViteSSG(
  // the root component
  App,
  // vue-router options
  { routes: router },
  // function to have custom setups
  ({ app, router, routes, isClient, initialState }) => {
    const pinia = createPinia()

    if (import.meta.env.SSR) {
      // this will be stringified and set to window.__INITIAL_STATE__
      initialState.pinia = pinia.state.value
    } else {
      // on the client side, we restore the state
      pinia.state.value = initialState?.pinia || {}
    }
    app.use(pinia)
    const pagesStore = usePagesStore(pinia)
    pagesStore.initialize()
  }
)
```

This is my store/pages.js

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const usePagesStore = defineStore('pages', {
  state: () => {
    return { pages: [] }
  },
  actions: {
    initialize() {
      console.log('initialize')
      fetch('https://localhost:44351/graphql/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          query: `
          query {
            contentAll {
              nodes {
                url
                name
                metaDescription: properties(
                  where: { alias: { eq: "metaDescription" } }
                ) {
                  value {
                    ... on BasicPropertyValue {
                      value
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }`
        })
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
          this.pages = result.data.contentAll.nodes
          console.log('done loading data')
        })

      console.log('done')
    }
  },
  getters: {
    allPages: (state) => state.pages,
    getPageById: (state) => {
      return (pageUrl) => state.pages.find((page) => page.url === pageUrl)
    }
  }
})
```

App.vue

```html
<script>
import { useHead } from '@vueuse/head'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { usePagesStore } from './stores/pages'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  setup() {},
  mounted() {
    const pageStore = usePagesStore()

    const route = useRoute()
    const pageInfo = pageStore.getPageById(route.path)
    console.log(pageInfo)
    useHead({
      title: 'blabla',
      meta: [
        {
          name: 'description',
          content: 'Website description'
        }
      ]
    })
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <div class="sidenav" :class="{ 'is-open': menuIsOpen }">
    <div class="sidenav-extended">
      <div class="sidenav-extended__menu-items">
        <router-link to="/" @click="toggleMenu">Home</router-link>
        <router-link to="/blogs" @click="toggleMenu">Blog</router-link>
        <router-link to="/about" @click="toggleMenu">About</router-link>
      </div>
      <input placeholder="Search..." class="sidenav-extended__search" />
    </div>
    <div class="sidenav-buttons">
      <div class="sidenav-buttons__top">
        <img src="@/assets/vue.svg" class="sidenav-buttons__logo" />
        <div class="menu-icon" @click="toggleMenu">
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidenav-bottom">
        <div class="sidenav-bottom__tags" @click="toggleMenu">
          <font-awesome-icon icon="fas fa-tags" />
        </div>
        <div class="sidenav-bottom__search" @click="toggleMenu">
          <font-awesome-icon icon="fas fa-magnifying-glass" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <router-view :key="$route.path" />
  </div>
</template>
```

I cannot get the right data in the meta head and pagetitle, because pinia is instantiated after getting the data.

How can I set the pagetitle and metadescription correctly?

Answer (score 0):

vite-ssg doesn't use mounted() function but rather serverPrefetch() function - so try adding a serverPrefetch function, and make sure you use await on the fetch as you want it to complete the fetches before rendering to html.

The serverPrefetch is only called during ssg so you'll still want your mounted function as well. You could put that into a separate function and call from both mounted() and serverPrefetch()

**alternatively**

Look at https://github.com/antfu/vite-ssg#async-components you may need to allow the initialization to complete so e.g.

```
if (import.meta.env.SSR) {
  // this will be stringified and set to window.__INITIAL_STATE__
  onSSRAppRendered(() => {
    initialState.pinia = pinia.state.value
  })
} else {
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I've adjusted it, but how can I go about preloading the Pinia-data (I need to fetch the routes and the meta-information) before loading the page itself?

Comment: Which did you do, the serverPrefetch or the onSSRAppRendered? If the latter, you could try doing some debugging to see when that function is called. Perhaps before setting the initialState you can fetch from the server. Try using async/await on that function.

Comment: serverPrefetch cannot be ran on the main.js in the `export const createApp = ViteSSG(` right? Or am I missing something here? The onSSRAppRendered I tried in the app.js, but to no avail.